# TFS Requirements Overview Report showing wrong data

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

I have an interesting issue with TFS reports.  When I run the QUERY: Team Queries->Planning and Tracking->Work Breakdown, I see the correct information, which is to say that I see the work items, etc. that are entered into TFS.  However, when I run the REPORT: Reports->Project Management->Requirements Overview I see that same data PLUS data that is no longer in the system.

Important information:
* I am using TFS 2010
* When I originally created this project, I used a Microsoft Project plan to upload the work items.  Before my team started using it, I decided to forget about Project and just use the web/studio interface, so I used the query "Delete all items" to clean the database.

While the clean worked in all other cases, this report seems to be holding on to those items, and I would like to know if there is a way to fix that.  It has been several weeks, and I ran the cube reports to see if it was updating (everything updates fine).

Anyone have a clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the query that you talk about, but if you do a delete of workitems, the delete may not have been propagated to your warehouse (and subsequently the cube).  If you have a relatively small number of WorkItems in your TFSWorkItemTracking database, it may be a good idea to rebuild your TFSWarehouse, which will then refresh your cube.

<strike>Take a look at the `SetupWarehouse.exe` command, which should be installed on your Application Tier.  This could take anywhere from an hour to a day to run, depending on your version control and work item tracking database, so you may want to do it off hours.  It shouldn't affect the day-to-day execution of TFS, just the reports.</strike>

*The above is for TFS 2008 Only. Per Matthew below, here's the answer for TFS 2010*

> From what I found SetupWarehouse.exe
>   no longer exists with TFS2010. In the
>   Administration Console, under
>   Application Tier->Reporting, there is
>   an option called "Start Rebuild".
>   Using this completely resolved my
>   problem. Thank you. It should be noted
>   that there is NO feedback from
>   clicking on "Start Rebuild". At first
>   it looked like the admin panel hung,
>   then it came back without feedback. It
>   took about an hour for reports to
>   start working again, which is the only
>   way I knew it was done.

If you ever get into the situation again where you need to permanently get rid of one or more workitems, you should get the TFS Power Tools.  The TFPT utility has a "destroywi" command that allows you to permanently (and safely) remove workitems from TFS.

Power Tools are available here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963

Comment: While the answer you provided does not work with TFS2010, it did point me in the right direction. From what I found SetupWarehouse.exe no longer exists with TFS2010.
In the Administration Console, under Application Tier->Reporting, there is an option called "Start Rebuild".  Using this completely resolved my problem.  Thank you.

It should be noted that there is NO feedback from clicking on "Start Rebuild".  At first it looked like the admin panel hung, then it came back without feedback.  It took about an hour for reports to start working again, which is the only way I knew it was done.